# Displaying new results currently being filtered out

Tags: filter, sorting, messages, alerts, messaging

I'm currently working on a messaging tool and one request was being able to filter the conversations by (Internal Team / Customers / Flagged)

One thing we're running into is what happens when a new message comes in that is currently being filtered out...and it might be a customer that needs a quick response.

One thought is to display a small banner at the top of the inbox stating that "1 New message being filter out"...but we also don't want to annoy users that are aware that the filter is blocking the incoming results.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

[image: UI]

Comment: Question: Why do you believe it'll annoy the user when they are filtering out the messages? If it's a customer that needs an urgent response isn't that highly necessary to ensure your business keeps moving forward?

Comment: You are correct but I was thinking about it from the other end. If I actively filtered out my internal team to focus on customers, I might be annoyed by continuously being notified that I have unread messages from them.

Comment: There are subtle ways to notify someone. A notification doesn't have to be a disruptive experience.

Comment: True. A "disruptive experience" can be very subjective though. Did you have any suggestions for the proposed situation?

Answer (score 1):

I made an explanation [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130512/how-should-i-handle-search-when-data-keeps-updating-via-websockets/130522#130522) to a conceptually similar problem.

> To say, I'd prefer to display users a notification banner (or there
>   might be more proper term calling it exactly) on top of the page.

Making the notification text's background color slightly disabled is key here to make this effect but feel free to try some other options in order to be sure it has same effect.

[image: Stackoverflow example]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this banner allow the user to perform any action or is it just informing them that new results are available? Is it persistent?

Comment: It's used to give the idea that an extra incoming results for that page available so that you may add these results (new massages that suits the filtering criteria in that case) to the existing page, like applying on top of it. It's better not refreshing the whole page since they're instant messages.

Comment: Thanks Erhan. I think we are going to test out a similar approach. If an incoming message is being hidden by active filters a subtle banner will push down from the top that states... 

[New message received. Clear Filters (x) ] 

The Clear Filters text will be styled as a text link and clear all active filters and if they dismiss the message we won't display it again for the remainder of the current session.

Comment: @Franklin-KC Happy if I could help. You may upvote and mark as an accepted answer if it’s so.